# Error in wso2 rest service call

Tags: web-services, wso2

I am calling a rest service from wso2 sequence with json input.If I call the service from PostMan the service returns proper output but when I try with WSO2 there is below error coming.

```
ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:138)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
```

Comment: Can you share your configs? Sample response will be helpful to isolate the cause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 ERROR White spaces are required between publicId and systemId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821342/wso2-esb-4-8-1-error-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid)