# Error during calling rest service from wso2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, apache-synapse, axiom, wso2-esb

I am calling a rest service from wso2 sequence with json input.If I call the service from PostMan the service returns proper output but when I try with WSO2 there is below error coming.Please help me .

I read some previous posts with same problem but In my case all requests are failing.

```
RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
```

Comment: Only the first request fails like this or all the requests fails? There is a bug reposted already, have a look [WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 ERROR White spaces are required between publicId and systemId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821342/wso2-esb-4-8-1-error-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid)

Comment: All the requests fails.Please suggest any solution for the same I need to do it in production environment.

Comment: This is not the same as above because in my case all the requests are failing so please help me.